# Row value equal to the row value itself plus the following rows up to the next non-null value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

The title is a bit confusing, but I think an example would make it clear.

I have this dataframe:

| Date | Info |
| --- | --- |
| 27/07/2022 | This is |
| NAN | an |
| NAN | example |
| 28/07/2022 | and this |
| NAN | is another one |

And this is my desired output:

| Date | Info |
| --- | --- |
| 27/07/2022 | This is an example |
| 28/07/2022 | and this is another one |

I tried few attempts with `fillna(method="ffil")` but I wasn't able to come with a solution. and I can't think of anything able to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initalize the input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["27/07/2022", np.NaN, np.NaN, "28/07/2022", np.NaN],
    "Info": ["This is", "an", "example", "and this", "is another one"]
})
```

Forward fill the dates

```
df.Date = df.Date.ffill()
```

group by date and concat string

```
df.Info = df.groupby(df.Date)["Info"].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

Drop duplicates to get the result

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Result:

```
         Date                     Info
0  27/07/2022       This is an example
3  28/07/2022  and this is another one
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `groupby` and `agg` after `ffill`-ing the `Date` column:

```
df.assign(Date=df['Date'].ffill()).groupby('Date',as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
         Date                     Info
0  27/07/2022       This is an example
1  28/07/2022  and this is another one
```